# Crystal Reports windows server 2008 to Windows server 2012 R2 throws Logon Error with .NET 2.0

Tags: crystal-reports, .net-2.0

I am working on Crystal Reports 10.5.3700.0 with windows server 2008 in .net Environment working fine. But not working with Windows server 2012 R2 throws Logon Error with .NET 2.0.

Already given full permission to Temp folder no use.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Visual Studio Report Designer > Verify Database i found the wrong xsd(datasource) path mapped. I changed that which is working fine.